# Conversion of formula to Prenex Normal Form

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

A question about formula conversion to prenex normal form:

Does this formula convert to 1 or 2 or both of them are incorrect ?

∃x∃y∀z S(x,y,z) ∨ ∀x∃z∃y S(x,y,z)  ~

1. ∃x∃y∀z∀g∃h (S(x,y,z) ∨ S(g,y,h))
2. ∃x∃y∀z∀g∃h∃j (S(x,y,z) ∨ S(g,j,h))

And is this conversion correct ?

∃x∃y∀z S(x,y,z) ∨ ∀x∃y∃z S(x,y,z) ~
∃x∃y∀z∀g∃h (S(x,y,z) ∨ S(g,y,h))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the conversion you listed are not correct,
For $(2)$, it rewrited $x$ as $g$, $z$ as $h$ and $y$ as $j$ and didn't change the order of the quantifier, correct!
$$∃x∃y∀z S(x,y,z) ∨ \color{orange}{∀x}\color{blue}{∃z}\color{red}{∃y} S(x,y,z)\equiv∃x∃y∀z\color{orange}{∀g}\color{blue}{∃h}\color{red}{∃j} (S(x,y,z) ∨ S(g,j,h))\tag*{$\require{enclose}
\enclose{box}[mathcolor="green"]{\unicode{x2714}}$}$$
But for $(1)$ the order changed, the equivalence which will not hold.
we can put $g,h$ anywhere before $y$, but not after.
The idea is do not change the order of the quantifier, to fix $(1)$ we can write:

\begin{align}
∃x∃y∀z S(x,y,z) ∨ \color{orange}{∀x}\color{blue}{∃z}\color{red}{∃y} S(x,y,z)
&\equiv ∃x\color{orange}{∀g}\color{blue}{∃h}\color{red}{∃y}∀z(S(x,y,z) ∨  S(g,y,h))\\
\end{align}

Similar problem for the last expression, order changed,
Since we want $x$ before $y$, and $z$ after $y$, to fix it we can write:

\begin{align}
∃x∃y∀z S(x,y,z) ∨ ∃x\color{orange}{∀x}\color{red}{∃y}\color{blue}{∃z} S(x,y,z)
&\equiv∃x\color{orange}{∀g}\color{red}{∃y}\color{blue}{∃h}∀z (S(x,y,z) ∨ S(g,y,h))
\end{align}

In conclusion, $(2)$ is the only correct conversion listed above.

Comment: Thank you, been searching for hours on the web. It's hard to find the anwsers when you are learning it in your native language and some of the definitions do not translate directly.